# Decode function SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a drop down field in my application for 'Ethnicity' with 4 possible values in it. I was using the value to populate a placeholder in a letter. There was an individual logic for each value to populate [X] across it, when it was selected in the application. For e.g: when 'Asian' was selected, a crossed bracket was there against it. And when not selected, there used to be a blank bracket, which used to look like the following.

```
    [ ] White
    [ ] Black
    [X] Asian
    [ ] Other
```

The code was as below:

```
    SELECT
    DECODE(
    lower(ml.ethnicity),
    'Asian',
    '[X]',
    '[ ]'
    )
    FROM
    pat_race pr,
    m_ethnicity ml
    WHERE
    ml.ethnicity_id (+) = pr.ethnicity_id
    AND
    pr.pat_id =xyz;
```

Likewise there were 4 logics for the 4 values which were then used as placeholders in a letter.

Now the ethnicity field is changed from drop down to multiple selection field.

So on choosing multiple ethnicity in the application for a single patient, i am getting a disoriented output in the letter like below.

On choosing 2 ethnicities, the output looks as below:

```
    [ ],[X] White
    [ ],[ ] Black
    [X],[ ] Asian
    [ ],[ ] Other
```

On choosing 3 ethnicities, the output looks as below:

```
    [ ],[X],[ ] White
    [ ],[ ],[X] Black
    [X],[ ],[ ] Asian
    [ ],[ ],[ ] Other
```

I need to have the output as below when multiple values are seleted:

```
    [X] White
    [X] Black
    [X] Asian
    [ ] Other
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide test case so I tried to imagine what you have. Here's only the necessary column set for both tables:

```
SQL> create table m_ethnicity (ethnicity_id number, ethnicity varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table pat_race (ethnicity_id number, ethnicity varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into pat_race
  2    select 100, 'Asian' from dual union all
  3    select 200, 'Black' from dual union all
  4    select 300, 'White' from dual union all
  5    select 400, 'Other' from dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> insert into m_ethnicity values (100, 'Asian');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

If you use such a query, the result is OK:

```
SQL> select case when ml.ethnicity = 'Asian' then '[x]'
  2              when ml.ethnicity = 'White' then '[x]'
  3              when ml.ethnicity = 'Black' then '[x]'
  4              when ml.ethnicity = 'Other' then '[x]'
  5              else '[ ]'
  6         end res,
  7         pr.ethnicity
  8  from pat_race pr left join m_ethnicity ml on ml.ethnicity_id = pr.ethnicity_id;

RES                  ETHNICITY
-------------------- ----------
[x]                  Asian
[ ]                  Other
[ ]                  Black
[ ]                  White

SQL>
```

OK; what if another ethnicity is selected (i.e. *inserted* into a table):

```
SQL> insert into m_ethnicity values (300, 'White');

1 row created.

SQL> select case when ml.ethnicity = 'Asian' then '[x]'
  2              when ml.ethnicity = 'White' then '[x]'
  3              when ml.ethnicity = 'Black' then '[x]'
  4              when ml.ethnicity = 'Other' then '[x]'
  5              else '[ ]'
  6         end res,
  7         pr.ethnicity
  8  from pat_race pr left join m_ethnicity ml on ml.ethnicity_id = pr.ethnicity_id;

RES                  ETHNICITY
-------------------- ----------
[x]                  Asian
[x]                  White
[ ]                  Other
[ ]                  Black

SQL>
```

Looks OK, i.e. just like you want it.

Now, if this isn't what you need, please - provide test case - not as a comment, but by editing the initial message you posted.